# Change color of gradient based on user selection

Tags: javascript, css, linear-gradients

I am trying to change the color of a gradient depending on user selection, I have everything working but I just don't know how to change the gradient using the format I have. (`change.style.background = "linear-gradient(90deg, color1, red)";`).

```js
const len = document.querySelectorAll("input").length;
let change = document.querySelector(".body");

for (let x = 0; x < len; x++) {
    document.querySelectorAll("input")[x].addEventListener("input", function() {
        let color1 = this.value;
        if (this.getAttribute("name")==="color1") {
            change.style.background = "linear-gradient(90deg, color1, red)";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.body{
  background:linear-gradient(90deg, blue, red);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body class="body">
    <h1>Background Generator</h1>
    <input type="color" name="color1" value="#996DAD">
    <input type="color" name="color2" value="#23AD23">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i only am testing the first input, i did not want to try both at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to have the color picker values dynamically inserted into the CSS.

Also, instead of looping over all the elements and then setting up event handlers for each of the `input` elements, you can leverage ["event delegation"](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and only set up one event handler.

```js
const picker1 = document.querySelector("input[name='color1']");
const picker2 = document.querySelector("input[name='color2']");

// No need to loop over all the input elements and set up an event
// handler for each. Just set up one event handler at a common ancestor
// of the elements you care about and let the event bubble up to be 
// handled there
document.addEventListener("input", function(event){
  // Now test to see if the event was triggered by an element you 
  // wish to handle
  if(event.target.classList.contains("colorPicker")){
    // Use template literals to insert JS values into a string:
    document.body.style.background = 
      `linear-gradient(90deg, ${picker1.value}, ${picker2.value})`;
  }
});
```

```css
.body{
  background:linear-gradient(90deg, blue, red);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      </head>
      <body class="body">
        <h1>Background Generator</h1>
        <input type="color" name="color1" value="#996DAD" class="colorPicker">
        <input type="color" name="color2" value="#23AD23" class="colorPicker">
    
        <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: will do. also thanks for the knowledge on bubbling and capturing. I am looking into that now. Very good information.